# Как при нажатии на checkbox менять результат вывода

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Вот мой код:

```
       <input type="text" name="inputValue" id="inputValue" value="" />
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxInput" id="checkboxInput" />
   </form>
   <div>Подоходный налог: <span id="incomeTax"></span></div>
   <div>Профсоюзный налог <span id="unionTax"></span></div>
   <div>Чистая зарплата: <span id="netSalary"></span></div>

   <script>
       // Инпуты:
       const inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue');
       const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkboxInput')

       // Подоходный налог:
       const incomeTaxValue = document.getElementById('incomeTax');

       // Профсоюзный налог: 
       const unionTaxValue = document.getElementById('unionTax');

       // Чистая зарплата:
       const netSalaryValue = document.getElementById('netSalary')



       // Функция которая считает все налоги.
       function calcTax() {
           // Число которое ввели в инпут:
           let inputNumber = inputValue.value;

           // Считаем подоходный налог:
           let incomeTax = (inputNumber - (inputNumber * (1 - 13 / 100)));
           // Выводим результат с фиксированным значением после комы не больше 2 знаков.
           incomeTaxValue.innerText = incomeTax.toFixed(2);

           // Считаем профсоюзный налог:
           let unionTax = inputNumber - (inputNumber * (1 - 1 / 100));
           // Выводим результат с фиксированным значением после комы не больше 2 знаков.
           unionTaxValue.innerText = unionTax.toFixed(2);

           let netSalary;
           // Считаем чистую зарплату :
           if (checkbox.checked) {
               netSalary = inputNumber - incomeTax;
           } else {
               netSalary = inputNumber - incomeTax - unionTax;
           }
           // Выводим результат с фиксированным значением после комы не больше 2 знаков.
           netSalaryValue.innerText = netSalary.toFixed(2);
       }



       inputValue.addEventListener('keydown', calcTax);
   </script>
```

Надо чтобы при изменении состояния checkbox профсоюзный налог не учитывался и чистая зарплата выводила другой результат, но результат меняется только когда начинаю вводить число в инпут, а нужно чтобы и при вводе инпута и при нажатии на чекбокс, как сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так хотели?

```js
// Инпуты:
const inputValue = document.getElementById('inputValue');
const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkboxInput')

// Подоходный налог:
const incomeTaxValue = document.getElementById('incomeTax');

// Профсоюзный налог: 
const unionTaxValue = document.getElementById('unionTax');

// Чистая зарплата:
const netSalaryValue = document.getElementById('netSalary')



// Функция которая считает все налоги.
function calcTax() {
   // Число которое ввели в инпут:
   let inputNumber = inputValue.value;

   // Считаем подоходный налог:
   let incomeTax = (inputNumber - (inputNumber * (1 - 13 / 100)));
   // Выводим результат с фиксированным значением после комы не больше 2 знаков.
   incomeTaxValue.innerText = incomeTax.toFixed(2);

   // Считаем профсоюзный налог:
   let unionTax = inputNumber - (inputNumber * (1 - 1 / 100));
   // Выводим результат с фиксированным значением после комы не больше 2 знаков.
   unionTaxValue.innerText = unionTax.toFixed(2);

   let netSalary;
   // Считаем чистую зарплату :
   if (checkbox.checked) {
       netSalary = inputNumber - incomeTax;
   } else {
       netSalary = inputNumber - incomeTax - unionTax;
   }
   // Выводим результат с фиксированным значением после комы не больше 2 знаков.
   netSalaryValue.innerText = netSalary.toFixed(2);
}



inputValue.addEventListener('keydown', calcTax);

checkbox.addEventListener('click', calcTax);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inputValue" id="inputValue" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxInput" id="checkboxInput" />

<div>Подоходный налог: <span id="incomeTax"></span></div>
<div>Профсоюзный налог <span id="unionTax"></span></div>
<div>Чистая зарплата: <span id="netSalary"></span></div>
```

Comment: Да, большое спасибо)